# Cannot start pyenv via pyenv init

Tags: python-3.x, pyenv

My mac us using pyenv and I am suddenly having this error message when I run pyenv init. it was working before.

```
➜  ddp-etl git:(main) ✗ pyenv init                       
# Load pyenv automatically by appending
# the following to 
~/.zprofile (for login shells)
and ~/.zshrc (for interactive shells) :

export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"

# Restart your shell for the changes to take effect.
```

1. So should I run these three commands in my ~/.zprofile?

   export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
   command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
   eval "$(pyenv init -)"
2. Why is it happening suddenly? I just dont want to fix something without knowing what I am doing and struggle in the long run

UPDATE:

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

I added these lines in ~/.zshrc and restarted the shell and even the laptop. Still I am getting the error